# Printing List as string in python

Tags: python, string, list

I am newbie to python 
Want to search for string file if found print line 
and want to  print output as

```
"mapp1=2"
"map2=6"
"MAP3"
```

Sample code :

```
import os
fname = "xx.txt"

new_list=[]
f=open(fname,'r')
for line in f :
    key = line.strip().split('\n')
    matching = [s for s in key if ("mapping" or "MAP") in s]
    if matching:
       if not line.startswith("#"):
           new_list.append((key))

print new_list

values = ','.join(str(i) for i in new_list)
print values

failed_res = ','.join(str(j) for j in values)
print failed_res
```

Output for this code is:

```
[mapp1=2],[map2=6],[MAP]
```

Please give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
','.join(str(i) for i in new_list)
```

by

```
'\n'.join(str(i).replace('[', '"').replace(']', '"') for i in new_list)
```

Output:

```
"mapp1=2"
"map2=6"
"MAP"
```

Also, don't forget to `f.close()` at the end of your script.

Comment: You can also use regular expresson to get rid of the brackets  `re.sub(r'[\[\]]', '','[abc]')`. There might be other options to do that depending on how your input actually looks like.

Comment: @Dawid right, although I think I'll regex are an overkill here and I'll stick with `.replace()`